# USb driver Document scanner for windows mobile

Tags: mobile, sdk, usb, driver, document

Does anyone know a USB driver/ SDK to user a USB Document scanner on a windows mobile device ?

Comment: what version of Windows Mobile?

Comment: The manufacture does not have a driver, I am searching for a alternative

Answer (score 0):

First of all, in order to use a USB peripheral with a Windows Mobile device, the device needs to support USB Host mode. If the device accepts flash drives and/or HID devices (like a mouse or keyboard) then host mode is supported. Other than that there is very little built-in support for USB periperals. Most peripheral manufacturers do not provide USB drivers for Windows Mobile. If the scanner can be configured as USB Mass Storage, it will probably work with a USB Host capable device. If the scanner supports the PTP protocol, there are some third party digital camera drivers that may work. Other than that, you would need to write a custom driver.